# How do you determine the % ratio between two constant values in PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a PHP web application where I am trying to retrieve two columns from a table, the Date and Attendance with a value of 0 (Present) or 1 (Absent).

[image: Attendance Table]

I'm using this code to retrieve these values that only lie on a weekday and the user logged into the session into the `$row` variable:

```
SELECT Date, Att_Type FROM Attendance WHERE (ID=$ID) AND (WEEKDAY(Date) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 AND WEEK(Date) = WEEK(now()))
```

Now what I want to do is take all the records of Monday (using Weekday value) and calculate the % of how many of those records for that one day has a 0 or 1. This would be repeated for everyday to today's day.

So for example, today is Thursday; Monday has 5 attendance logs of 0,1,0,1,1 so the % Present is 40% and Absent is 60% and so on for Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday **if there is a record**, else 0%.

Comment: `100 * SUM(att_type) / COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY WEEKDAY(DATE)`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Incidentally, while it may seem a bit of a mouthful, `Date > WEEK(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY 
AND date <= WEEK(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 7 DAY` (or something like that) will be much more efficient than a function comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar already answered this, I just write the full SQL.

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(Date) AS weekday,
    100 * SUM(Att_Type) / COUNT(Att_Type) AS percentage
FROM Attendance 
WHERE ID=$ID
AND WEEK(Date) = WEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(Date)
```

This will get you percentage of all weekdays from 0 to 6, you can pick only 0 - 4 from the result.